# Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ ... /wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, apache, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a django app on aws beanstalk but I get a 500.

I get the ImportError and I have tried all what the web has suggested, I think, to no end.

The trace from the aws server log:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.126990 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055] mod_wsgi (pid=11381): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/src/kirr/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127048 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055] mod_wsgi (pid=11381): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/src/kirr/wsgi.py'.
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127087 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127244 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "/opt/python/current/app/src/kirr/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127252 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127347 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127354 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127446 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127453 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127584 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127602 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]     self._setup(name)
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127630 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127635 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127655 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127659 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127780 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127786 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127802 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127818 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127831 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127843 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127854 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127865 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127881 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sun Mar 26 02:55:17.127902 2017] [:error] [pid 11381] [remote 127.0.0.1:45055] ImportError: No module named 'kirr'
```

The **wsgi.py** file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "kirr.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/**wsgi.conf**:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On

<VirtualHost *:80>

Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/src/kirr/wsgi.py


<Directory /opt/python/current/app/>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
  python-path=/opt/python/current/app:/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages:/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages user=wsgi group=wsgi \
  home=/opt/python/current/app
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi
</VirtualHost>

LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

There are two config files in my django app located inside `.elasticbeanstalk`:

```
.elasticbeanstalk/**01_Packages.config**:
`packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    mysql-server: []
    mysql: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []`

.elasticbeanstalk/**02_Python.config**:
`container_commands:
    01_migrate:
            command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python src/manage.py migrate --noinput"
        leader_only: true
    02_createsu:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python src/manage.py createsu"
        leader_only: true
    03_collectstatic:
        command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python src/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: “kirr.settings"
        "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/src:$PYTHONPATH"
        "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: src/kirr/wsgi.py
            NumProcesses: 3
            NumThreads: 20
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
        "/static/": "www/static/"
```

This is what I have tried:

ATTEMPT 1: [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620725/target-wsgi-script-wsgi-py-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module) suggested it could be a python version issue. I re-built my django app using python 3.4, same as on beanstalk, but there was no effect.

ATTEMPT 2: As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525736/django-serving-wsgi-py-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module), I have changed the privileges of the wsgi file. To do this, I ssh into beanstalk (`eb ssh`), cd to directory and then:

```
$ sudo chmod a+x wsgi.py
```

No effect.

ATTEMPT 3, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280166/mod-wsgi-pid-2179-target-wsgi-script-opt-graphite-conf-graphite-wsgi-canno), I have changed the SOLINUX value to disabled as:

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-112-31-10-129 src]$ sudo nano /etc/selinux/semanage.conf
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

So, apparently I had saved the config files in the wrong folder. `.elasticbeanstalk/` instead of `. ebextensions/`. Using the latter fixed the problem.

Remember to force git-add if the git does not want to add the hidden folder, as:

```
git add -f .ebextensions/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
    python-home=/opt/python/run/venv \
    python-path=/opt/python/current/app/src \
    user=wsgi group=wsgi
```

You had incorrect path for what is the parent directory of your project. Also not using preferred method for declaring where the Python virtual environment is located.

On the latter, make sure you read the documentation:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Also refer to the Django documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Since you are only running the one WSGI application, also recommended you set:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error. I accessed the /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf via `eb ssh` and edited the python-home to point to venv, and python-path to the .../src but I get the same error. I am also not sure how to make these changes via the config files, so that they persist after each `eb deploy`. Thanks