# Django rest api in Elastic beanstalk doesnt work but works in 127.0.0.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, wsgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-wsgi

I am having a serious issue with AWS elastic beanstalk and I don't know how to solve it.
I have deployed the DRF app in the elastic beanstalk. 
My Django rest framework works fine in 127.0.0.1 but it is its giving 500 internal server error in the elastic beanstalk server.

(The log file is too big so not uploading here.)

The most prominent error lines from logfile are-

```
1. mod_wsgi (pid=3890):
Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/beanalytic_project/wsgi.py' cannot 
be loaded as Python module.

----------

2.mod_wsgi (pid=3890): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 
'/opt/python/current/app/my_project/wsgi.py'.

----------

3.Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Nov 06 10:57:18.422431 2019] [:error] [pid 3890] [remote 
172.31.18.188:71]   File "/opt/python/current/app/my_project/wsgi.py", line 
16, in <module>
[Wed Nov 06 10:57:18.422436 2019] [:error] [pid 3890] [remote 
172.31.18.188:71]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Wed Nov 06 10:57:18.422443 2019] [:error] [pid 3890] [remote 
172.31.18.188:71]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
```

---

Please help. I really need it. Thank You.

The tutorial I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypnEf7W8db0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024615/target-wsgi-script-opt-python-current-app-wsgi-py-cannot-be-loaded-as-p

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: @error404 Nope not working, my issue is similar to this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=733213

Comment: It seems like elastic beanstalk doesn't support Django 2.2 with python 3.6. @error404. That's why I was having issues.